# Micronaut context configuration for test

Tags: java, testing, micronaut

I'm trying to write a basic controller test in a micronaut (3.2.7) application. When I run it, it fails to start as it wants to create DB related beans too. micronaut-hibernate-jpa, flyway, etc. are in the pom.xml.

**Can I configure the context somehow so it doesn't pick up hikaripool,flyway, and jpa realted beans?**

```
11:46:23.820 [main] INFO  i.m.context.env.DefaultEnvironment - Established active environments: [test]
11:46:24.112 [main] WARN  i.m.c.h.j.JpaConfiguration$EntityScanConfiguration - Runtime classpath scanning is no longer supported. Use @Introspected to declare the packages you want to index at build time. Example @Introspected(packages="foo.bar", includedAnnotations=Entity.class)
11:46:24.133 [main] INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - HikariPool-1 - Starting...
11:46:25.197 [main] ERROR com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool - HikariPool-1 - Exception during pool initialization.
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

The code:

```java
class HelloTest {

    private static EmbeddedServer server;
    private static HttpClient client;

    @BeforeAll
    public static void setupServer() {
        server = ApplicationContext.run(EmbeddedServer.class);
        client = server
            .getApplicationContext()
            .createBean(HttpClient.class, server.getURL());
    }

    @AfterAll
    public static void stopServer() {
        if (server != null) {
            server.stop();
        }
        if (client != null) {
            client.stop();
        }
    }

    @Test
    void testHelloWorldResponse() {
      ...
    }

}
```

I tried to exclude configurations like this, but with no luck:

```java
        server = ApplicationContext.builder("test")
            .exclude("io.micronaut.configuration.hibernate.jpa","io.micronaut.configuration.jdbc.hikari")
            .run(EmbeddedServer.class);
```

Note: If I remove everything from application.yml then the test works. It looks like that in tests the default properties are resolved which turns on jpa,metrics, etc. So I guess the test needs to ignore the default settings too somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the micronaut team on gitter and currenlty the only option is not having a default configuration and having multiple configuration files for controller, repo and e2e testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can override all of your (default) `application.yml` with (test-)environment specific property files: https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#_included_propertysource_loaders

So you can just provide a dedicated `application-mycustomtest.yml` as part of your test resources, in which you override all default settings.

Then you can specify as part of the test, [which environments shall be active](https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/):

```
@MicronautTest(environments={"mycustomtest"})
```

Comment: jpa or datasources doesn't have an enabled property so can't turn them off in the test properties. Renamed the default config to "live" so now it doesn't pick it up. But I don't prefer this way, I'd much rather do it in code. If the property files can control what to load, I should be able to control it from code too.